# Why won't tool strip button read checkbox status?

Tags: c#

I have a tool strip with a button which once clicked should delete data from a datagridview. I have added the correct code into the buttons function but once clicked nothing seems to happen. I've added the same code to a normal button and the code is executed correctly. I was wondering if there was any solution around this so that I can get the toolstrip button to execute my code correctly?
Thanks :)

My code:

```
    private void toolStripButton9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView4.Rows)
        {
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[25].Value))
            {

                DialogResult dlg = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete this lead?", "IMAGINE 2021 CRM",
                    MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
                if (dlg == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("DELETE from Leads where Lead_ID='" + row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "'", con);
                    sda.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    try
                    {
                        Directory.Delete(row.Cells["folderDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value.ToString(), true);
                    }
                    catch { }
                    con.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("Lead removed.", "IMAGINE 2021 CRM", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                        MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please put code as normal text, indented four spaces for each line.  NOT as an image.

Comment: Does it show the message box?

Comment: No, it doesn't seem to execute any of the code.

Comment: Did you debug the code? Does it hit any break point in `toolStripButton9_Click`?

Comment: Yes, I've tried a few different breakpoints throughout but it just doesn't seem to be reading the function. The button works fine when I add a simple command like open another form etc. but dosen't seem to work with my datagridview.

Comment: Try `if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[25].FormattedValue)) { .. }`

Comment: Nope, that didn't work.